# Inequality on Brownian motions and Ito integrals

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I know that Ito's integral isn't monotonic, i.e. if $X \le Y$ almost surely, then $\int_0^t X_s \, dX_s \le \int_0^t Y_s \, dY_s$ almost surely for $X,Y$ semi-martingales.
However, is it true that $\mathbb{P}\left(\int_0^t B_s \, dB_s \ge \int_0^t |B_s| \, dB_s\right) = 0$ for any Brownian motion $B$?

My try is the following:

1. Prove that $\int_0^t B_s - |B_s| \, dB_s$ is a martingale in $L^2$ for any $t \ge 0$, because the co-variation is bounded, i.e.
   $$\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\langle \int_0^t B_s - |B_s| \, dB_s, \int_0^t B_s - |B_s| \, dB_s\rangle_t \right|\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\left|\int_0^t B_s-|B_s|\, d\langle B,B\rangle_s\right|\right] < \infty$$
   and since the co-variation of a Brownian motion is $\langle B,B \rangle_s = s$ we obtain
   $$\int_0^t B_s - |B_s| \, ds$$
   which is bounded for any $t$ by $-2B_s \le B_s-|B_s| \le 0$ almost surely. Then, the co-variation is bounded from below by $-2t\sup_{s\le t} B_s$ and from above by $0$, and by Doob's inequality and taking the expected value of the co-variation we finally achieve
   $$\mathbb{E}[|\langle \int_0^t B_s - |B_s| \, dB_s, \int_0^t B_s - |B_s| \, dB_s\rangle_t|] \le 2t C \mathbb{E}[|B_t|] < +\infty$$
2. Since it is a martingale, we can use the Maximal inequality to bound the probability
   $$\mathbb{P}\left(\int_0^t B_s- |B_s| \, dB_s \ge \lambda \right) \le \frac{2}{\lambda} \mathbb{E}[|\int_0^t B_s- |B_s| \, dB_s|]$$
   however from this we cannot infer that it goes to $0$ since we don't know if
   $$\mathbb{E}[|\int_0^t B_s- |B_s| \, dB_s|] < +\infty$$
   nor that it goes to $0$.

Furthermore, I reckon that such method would suffice to show that both $\mathbb{P}\left(\int_0^t B_s \, dB_s \ge \int_0^t |B_s| \, dB_s\right) = 0$ and $\mathbb{P}\left(\int_0^t B_s \, dB_s \le \int_0^t |B_s| \, dB_s\right) = 0$ which can't be the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can not be true, since the process $M$ defined by
$$M_t = \int_0^t (|B_s|-B_s) ~\mathrm{d}B_s$$
is a martingale with expectation $0$. If it was non-negative almost surely, it would be null almost surely.

Informally, $\mathrm{d}B_s$ is not a measure, but when you integrate continuous adapted processes, you may approach it by random signed measures. That is why inequalities are not preserved by stochastic integration.

Comment: I don't really get the sentence ''If it was non-negative almost surely, it would be null almost surely'', we don't know $M_t$ is non-negative or am I missing something?

Comment: You ask whether $\int_0^t B_s \mathrm{d}B_s \le \int_0^t |B_s| \mathrm{d}B_s$ almost surely or not. If the answer was yes, the difference would be non-negative almost surely.

Comment: OK, I just misunderstood it. Thanks.